# To determine denseness of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the set $Y = \{X_1,\cdots,X_4\}$ where $X_1,\cdots,X_4$ are identically distributed but not necessarily independent random variables. The random variable $X_1$ (any $X_i, i \in [4]$), can take $n$ distinct values, say $a_1,\cdots,a_n$.

The set of possible distributions of $X_1$, $\Lambda = \{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n: \alpha \geq 0, \sum\limits_{j \in [n]} \alpha_j = 1\}$.

The set of possible distributions of $Y$, $\Gamma = \{\mu\in \mathbb{R}^{\overline{n}}: \mu \geq 0, \sum\limits_{j \in [\overline{n}]} \mu_j = 1\}$, where $\overline{n}$ is the number of possible "values" the set $Y$ can take. (I use sets instead of vectors because order is not important, i.e. $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is considered the same as $(a_2,a_4,a_3,a_1)$).

The set of possible distributions of $Y$ when $X_i$'s are independent, $\Gamma^I = \{\mu\in \mathbb{R}^{\overline{n}}: \mu(\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}) = \prod\limits_{j \in [4]}\alpha(b_j)$, where $b_j \in \{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ for all $j \in [4]$.

My question is, is the set $\Gamma^I$ dense in the set $\Gamma$?

I can see that $\Gamma^I$ is a measure zero set with respect to $\Gamma$ but not sure how to go about determining if it's dense or not.

PS: I have not tagged probability related topics because while the setting involves random variables, the question is purely related to denseness in Euclidean spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\Omega = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}^4$.
If $\mu \in \Gamma \backslash \Gamma^I$, there is some $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4) \in \Omega$ such that $\mu((b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)) \ne \prod_j \mu(\{x \in \Omega: x_j = b_j\})$.  This inequality will still be true for $\mu'$ if $\sum_{b\in\Omega} |\mu(b) - \mu'(b)|$ is sufficiently small.  Therefore it is not dense.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand how we can say the inequality will still be true for $\mu'$. E.g. $\mu$ can be as follows: $\mu(a_1,\cdots,a_4)=1, \mu(a)=0$ for all other $a \in \Omega$. In this case $\mu \in \Gamma \setminus \Gamma^I$. Then how should we construct $\mu'$? (But in this particular case probably additional issues may arise due to $\mu$ being a boundary point).

Comment: Now I'm confused.  If you mean that for probability measure $\mu$, $X_1 = a_1, \ldots, X_4 = a_4$ with probability $1$, this is in $\Gamma^I$.  If you mean each of the $24$ permutations of $(a_1, \ldots, a_4)$ has probability $1/24$, that's in $\Gamma \backslash \Gamma^I$ and, for example, $\mu((a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)) = 1/24$ while $\mu(\{x \in \Omega: x_j = a_j\}) = 1/4$, and $1/24 > 1/4^4$.  If $\mu'$ is sufficiently close to $\mu$, $\mu'((a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4))$ will be close to $1/24$, say $> 1/25$, and $\mu'(\{x\in \Omega: x_j = a_j\})$ will be close to $1/4$, say $< 1/3.9$, and $1/25 > 1/3.9^4$.